# single regex to get multiple pattern with multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

Criteria to achieve with regex pattern for the input text is,

- Support at-least one Uppercase letter
- Support at-least one Lowercase letter
- Support at-least one Special character listed --> @ % $
- Support at-least one Digit

No Start and End Criteria.

Trying to achieve with below single regex,

```
^(
  (\w+\d+[@%\$]+)
     |
     (\d+[@%\$]+\w+)
        |
        ([@%\$]+\d+\w+)
             |
             (\w+[@%\$]+\d+)
)$
```

Problem is,

Support for at-least one uppercase is not working.
I am pretty sure that it is not a good approach to build the regex pattern.

Please help me to achieve these criteria in single regex pattern.

Thanks in Advance!!!

### Pass Criteria

Test@123
tesT@123
@123tesT
123@Test
TTTTeeeess@@@@$$$111112222
@@@@$$$1111TTT@@@$$esss

### Fail Criteria

Test (No special character) 
@123 
123 
@ 
T 
test 
test@123   (No Uppercase) 
Test@123&  ('&' not to be supported in the pattern) 
@123test  
@TTT123   (No Lowercase)

Comment: Pass and Fail Criteria are different from the other related questions.(Solutions cant be achieved). Hence, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Tweeking the solutions provided in that questions are quite complicate for me where the answer is not easily understood by me. Apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@%$]).+$
```

Try this.This should do it.Each condition is satisfied using lookaheads.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/70

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do this, using [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^
(?=.*[A-Z])
(?=.*[a-z])
(?=.*[@%$])
(?=.*\d)
.*$
```